# $FWDIR does not point anywhere

Tags: linux, firewall, checkpoint

I have installed Check Point R75.20 splat. Check Point firewall logs can be accessed directly by using OPSEC LEA. For that I need to have a LEA connection.

Now to set up a LEA connection, I need to do the following steps:

1)In the FWDIR\conf directory on the computer where the Check Point Management
Server is installed, edit the fwopsec.conf file to include the following line:
lea_server  port 18184

2)...

**My problem** is that my **FWDIR** is **not pointing anywhere**. Furthermore, if I do a,

```
find / -name "fwopsec.conf"
```

I get no results.
When searching for the problem, I found that,

```
FWDIR=/opt/cpfw1-r55
```

but i dont see any directory as such in my checkpoint platform

I am stuck. What am I missing?
Thanks.

Comment: This is utterly off topic here, but what does it mean "FWDIR is not pointing anywhere"? When you log into expert mode and say "echo $FWDIR", what do you get? Also: do you have a separate management server, and if so, where is the problem, on the management server or on the gateway?

Comment: Sorry if that meant something else, but what i meant was that when I do a "echo $FWDIR", i get nothing. FWDIR should be set to some path isnt it. I am also unclear of the "place where the CheckPoint Management Server is installed". When i install Check Point R75.20 splat, where does the mgmt server get installed. Sorry if the question is off the track, but can you direct me somewhere so that i cam understand the thing clearly.

Comment: Obviously the Check Point customer service is the address to complain. FWDIR ought to be set to /opt/CPsuite-R75.20/fw1 or something like that (after you run the first-time setup wizard and reboot). If it's not, then you have done something seriously wrong, I'm not sure what could it be actually. Can you describe your installation procedure?

Comment: I had a the iso of the CheckPoint R75.20. I installed it in my VirtualBox. During the checkpoint secure platform installation, it asks for 1)Device List 2)Add Driver 3)Next Step. I headed straight to the next step in installation aftre the installer figured out that mys system was suitable. Then in network interface configuration, I entered a valid IP address, subnet ahd the default gateway IP, then i selected port 443 as the port for SecurePlatform Https web server fro system configuration via browser. Then the installation completed. ...(please see next comment)

Comment: I then changed the username and password logging into the system. I then switched to expert mode, tried echo $FWDIR, but got nothing. THis is what i did.

Comment: You have to complete the first-time setup wizard. Connect to your new machine with a browser over https, and follow the wizard.

Comment: I need to allow pop-ups for accessing it via https. THis is what appears in my browser https://192.168.1.111/webis/index.html?=openedAsPopup, now the link doesnot accept any inputs given by me and i cannot continue with the configuration. What might be the problem? Also i get a "xslProcessor.transformDocument is not a function".

Comment: Yes, you do need to explicitly allow pop-ups (and javascript). Sorry about that. The xls problem is a known limitation when using newer Firefox versions. Sorry about that too. You may have to install FF4 or IE in a virtual box to overcome that.

Comment: Oh, and since you have to use Windows anyway for the management console, you might just as well use IE.

Comment: I used IE and it worked. Thanks. Now in order to pull the logs from CheckPoint firewall, i did the following configuration changes:  lea_server auth_port 18184
lea_server auth_type ssl_opsec  on file $FWDIR/conf/fwopsec.conf. Now when i scan the server for open ports the port 18184 is not shown as the a open port. How is it that i pull the checkpoint firewall logs. Thanks.

Comment: i forgot to mention that after changing the fwopsec.conf file, i did a cpstop and a cpstart as well.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot help you any further as I have no kniwledge about OPSEC. Have you tried to talk to Check Point customer service?

Comment: Ok, I ll talk to CheckPoint customer service. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are facing any problems in locating `object.c`, `object_5_o.c`, and the rulebases file then you can try  another command that has to be run in expert mode:

```
cd /opt/CPsuite-R65/fw1/conf
```

and then type

```
ls -l
```

then you will be able to locate all these files, I too had this problem earlier in firewall installed on virtual box.